# On/Off FlipSwitch button with bootbox confirm

Tags: jquery, css, bootbox

I am using On/Off FlipSwitch for switching state but before switching it needs user confirmation. I am using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c73Yw/) example. Given example working fine with normal js `confirm`but I want to use [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/) confirm. I am trying [here](http://codepen.io/hasanuzzaman/pen/PZOjrW) but it is not not working.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. Now I update `here` link. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code ([demo](http://codepen.io/Mottie/pen/Verzrm?editors=001))

```
$('.onoffswitch').on('click', '.onoffswitch-label', function(event) {
  var checkbox = $(this).prev()[0];
  event.preventDefault();
  bootbox.confirm({
    message: "Are you sure ?",
    closeButton: false,
    callback: function(result) {
      if (result) {
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
        $(checkbox).change();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Your solution work fine but it causes another problem. There is an `change` event bind with `checkbox` that is not fire. http://codepen.io/hasanuzzaman/pen/gPXxeX

Comment: add `$(checkbox).change();` after the `checkbox.checked = ...`